# Android: storage location for data to be shared with other Apps?

Tags: android, caching, storage

I'm currently familar with the concepts of an application-own storage location and the external storage location that resides on an SD-card. But I'm not sure what to do in this scenario:

I'm writing some kind of library/open source classes that can be used by other applications too. These classes download some data and have to cache them on a public place. Now when an other application that uses the same classes is started it first checks if the required data are already available or not. If yes, the cached data have to be used, elsewhere it downloads the data for its own and stores them at the same public location where others can access them too.

My question: what would be the best place for this kind of public data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

External storage is suitable for this because files in internal storage will be private to your application.

You can get the path to external storage with `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`